# Does reliabilism fall to the problem of induction?

Tags: epistemology, induction

From what I've gathered, reliabilism states that epistemic justification occurs when someone forms a belief via truth-conducive methods. However, doesn't this fall to the problem of induction? Isn't reliabilism assuming that truth-conducive methods, or methods that have produced true beliefs in the past, will persist to be truth-conducive?

Comment: See book, Bertrand Russell, Human Knowledge, its Scope and Limits, Routledge (1948) (1992). Masterful treatment of the question.

Comment: See also book, Nicholas Maxwell, From knowledge to wisdom : a revolution in the aims and methods of science, B. Blackwell (1984). Be patient at the begining, it gets better as it goes along.